# Stored Procedure Check Values Before Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure that checks the IN values if there are any changes, and if there are proceed to update otherwise don't update.

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(
 IN id_ INT,
 IN data1_ VARCHAR(45),
 IN data2_ VARCHAR(45)
 )
 BEGIN
 DECLARE data1check varchar(45);
 DECLARE data2check varchar(45);

 SELECT data1, data2 FROM main AS B;
 SET data1check = B.data1;
 SET data2check = B.data2;

 IF (data1check <> data1_ OR data2check <> data2_)

 THEN

    UPDATE main SET 
    version = version + 1,
    data1 = COALESCE(data1_, data1), 
    data2 = COALESCE(data2_, data2) 
    WHERE id = id_;

 END IF;
 END
```

I tried it out with this query:

```
CALL new_procedure(1,'Violet','Green')
```

but i get:

```
Error Code: 1109 Unknown table 'B' in field list
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use?

```
SET data1check = main.data1;
SET data2check = main.data2;
```

Instead of

```
SET data1check = B.data1;
SET data2check = B.data2;
```